# How to filter null values from textboxes tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, filter

I am attempting to filter the input from my textboxes so none of the fields can contain null values and both the password and confirm password fields have to match. I thought I could accomplish this with a simple if statement. However, upon executing the statement with the "sign up" button I assigned to it I get the error "TypeError: get() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given". I tried removing the positional arguments by changing -

```
self.TBPW.get('1.0','end')
```

to -

```
self.TBPW.get()
```

However. Upon doing this I recieve the error "TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'". Any suggestions for how I can circumvent this?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Accounts:
    
    def __init__(self, win):
        self.root = win
        self.root.title('Google')
        self.root.geometry('500x500+600+200')
        self.root.configure(background='white')
        
        #Label First name
        self.lblFN = tk.Label(self.root,text = 'First name', font = ('Mundial Light', 8),bg = 'White',fg='dodger blue')
        self.lblFN.place(relx = 0.235, rely = 0.17, anchor = tk.SE)
        self.lblFN.focus()
        #Textbox First name
        self.TBFN = tk.Text(self.root)
        self.TBFN.config(font=('Mundial Light', 13),highlightbackground='dodger blue',highlightthickness=1)
        self.TBFN.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.19, height=25, width=175, anchor = tk.CENTER)
        
        #Label Last name
        self.lblLN = tk.Label(self.root,text = 'Last name', font = ('Mundial Light', 8),bg = 'White',fg='dodger blue')
        self.lblLN.place(relx = 0.635, rely = 0.17, anchor = tk.SE)
        self.lblLN.focus()
        #Textbox Last name
        self.TBLN = tk.Text(self.root)
        self.TBLN.config(font=('Mundial Light', 13),highlightbackground='dodger blue',highlightthickness=1)
        self.TBLN.place(relx = 0.7, rely = 0.19, height=25, width=175, anchor = tk.CENTER)

        #Label Username
        self.lblUN = tk.Label(self.root,text = 'Username', font = ('Mundial Light', 8),bg = 'White',fg='dodger blue')
        self.lblUN.place(relx = 0.235, rely = 0.3, anchor = tk.SE)
        self.lblUN.focus()
        #Textbox Username
        self.TBUN = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.TBUN.config(font=('Mundial Light', 13),highlightbackground='dodger blue',highlightthickness=1)
        self.TBUN.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.32, height=30, width=375, anchor = tk.CENTER)
        #Label @gmail
        self.lblGM = tk.Label(self.root,text = '@gmail.com', font = ('Mundial Light', 13),bg = 'white',fg='black')
        self.lblGM.place(relx = 0.87, rely = 0.345, anchor = tk.SE)
        self.lblGM.focus()
        
        #Label Password
        self.lblPW = tk.Label(self.root,text = 'Password', font = ('Mundial Light', 8),bg = 'White',fg='dodger blue')
        self.lblPW.place(relx = 0.235, rely = 0.45, anchor = tk.SE)
        self.lblPW.focus()
        #Textbox Password
        self.TBPW = tk.Text(self.root)
        self.TBPW.config(font=('Mundial Light', 13),highlightbackground='dodger blue',highlightthickness=1)
        self.TBPW.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.47, height=25, width=175, anchor = tk.CENTER)
        
        #Label Confirm
        self.lblCF = tk.Label(self.root,text = 'Confirm', font = ('Mundial Light', 8),bg = 'White',fg='dodger blue')
        self.lblCF.place(relx = 0.61, rely = 0.45, anchor = tk.SE)
        self.lblCF.focus()
        #Textbox Confirm
        self.TBCF = tk.Text(self.root)
        self.TBCF.config(font=('Mundial Light', 13),highlightbackground='dodger blue',highlightthickness=1)
        self.TBCF.place(relx = 0.7, rely = 0.47, height=25, width=175, anchor = tk.CENTER)

        #Sign up button
        self.btnSU = tk.Button(self.root, text = 'Sign Up', command = self.SignUp, bg='dodger blue',fg='white',font = ('Mundial Light', '10','bold'))
        self.btnSU.place(relx = 0.95, rely = 0.9, height=35, width=60, anchor = tk.SE)
        
    def SignUp(self):
        if self.TBPW.get('1.0','end') == self.TBCF.get('1.0','end') and self.TBPW.get('1.0','end') != '\n' and self.TBFN.get('1.0','end') != '\n' and self.TBLN.get('1.0','end') != '\n' and self.TBUN.get('1.0','end') != '\n':
            print("Good to go")
        else:
            print("Need to fix")
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    Accounts(root)
    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.TBUN` is an `Entry` widget, not `Text` widget. So `self.TBUN.get() == ''` should be used instead of `self.TBUN.get("1.0", "end") == '\n'`.

Better use `Entry` widget instead of `Text` widget for single line input.

Comment: Can't believe I made such a silly mistake! Much appreciated.